# can't figure out where this error is coming from: syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting keyword_end

Tags: ruby

I'm coming from a python background and I can't figure out why I'm getting the error message. I can't find where I'm not ending any of my loops. This works if I don't have everything into functions.

```
namelist = ["eric","lena","austin","booger"]
counter = 0
names = Hash.new

def start()
  puts "enter name"
  print "> "
  input = $stdin.gets.chomp
  namelist.push(input)
  more_names()
  hash_portion()
end

def more_names()
  puts "press 1 to add another name otherwise press 2 if you're done"
  print "> "
  choice = $stdin.gets.chomp

  if choice == 1
    puts "> "
    input1 = $stdin.gets.chomp
    namelist.push(input1)
    more_names()
  elsif choice == 2
    nil
  else
    more_names()
  end
end

def hash_portion()
  until counter == namelist.length do
    n_namelist = namelist.sample(1000000000000)
    n_namelist.each do |n|
      counter += 1
      names ["#{counter}"] = "#{n}"
    end
  end

  names.each do |digit,person|
    puts "#{digit}. #{person}"
  end
end

start()
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the whitespace in this line:

```
names ["#{counter}"] = "#{n}"
```

Must look like this:

```
names["#{counter}"] = "#{n}"
```

Comment: That worked. Thank you very much! I've been scratching my head about this all day.